# BeautifulSoup html5lib parsing strange phenomenon ..is that a bug?

Tags: beautifulsoup, html5lib

python2.6 + htmllib0.99 + bs4

When you run the following code will throw an exception

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -------_*_ coding: utf-8 _*_

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html5lib    
html  = '''
<html>
<head>
<title> test
</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tcp">hello</div>
</body>
</html>
'''
cs = BeautifulSoup(html,"html5lib")
print cs.contents[0].contents[2].contents[1]['id']
main_tag = cs.find('div', id='tcp')

print main_tag.text


####result####

#tcp
#Traceback (most recent call last):
#  File "C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\Desktop\test.py", line 21, in <
#    print main_tag.text
#AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

After removing the space between "<title>" and "test" ,the program will run successfully

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in bs4. See:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/1430633

There are situations in which bs4 generates a malformed tree. Then "find" runs off the end of the tree, and returns a None.